# worldweatheronline API response error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsonp

I am trying to pull weather info from 'worldweatheronline' using an $http call in angular factory:

```
this.testApi = function(coords) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.jsonp(API_ROOTS + '?key=9834687w634087623eg8932te&q=' + coords.latitude + ',' + coords.longitude + '&cc=yes&includeLocation=yes&format=json')
        .then(function(response) {
          deferred.resolve(response.current_condition);
          console.log(response.current_condition);
        }, function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        }
        );
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

and controller:

```
$scope.updateLocalWeather = function() {
      $geolocation.get().then(
        function(position) {
          $weather.testApi(position.coords).then(
            function(weather) {
              $scope.localWeather = weather;

                $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();

            }
          );
        }
      );
    };
```

and from the console it shows an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

but the response comes through when I console.log:

```
{ "data": { "current_condition": [ {"cloudcover": "0", "FeelsLikeC": "11", "FeelsLikeF": "51", "humidity": "42", "observation_time": "07:29 AM", "precipMM": "0.0", "pressure": "1029", "temp_C": "11", "temp_F": "51", "visibility": "10", "weatherCode": "113",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Sunny" } ],  "weatherIconUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/cdn.worldweatheronline.net\/images\/wsymbols01_png_64\/wsymbol_0001_sunny.png" } ], "winddir16Point": "SW", "winddirDegree": "235", "windspeedKmph": "4", "windspeedMiles": "2" } ],  "nearest_area": [ { "areaName": [ {"value": "Randjesfontein" } ],  "country": [ {"value": "South Africa" } ], "latitude": "-25.952", "longitude": "28.143", "population": "0",  "region": [ {"value": "Gauteng" } ],  "weatherUrl": [ {"value": "http:\/\/www.worldweatheronline.com\/v2\/weather.aspx?q=-25.9484274,28.1395815" } ] } ],  "request": [ {"query": "Lat -25.95 and Lon 28.14", "type": "LatLon" } ],  "weather": [ { "astronomy": [ {"moonrise": "09:08 PM", "moonset": "08:47 AM", "sunrise": "06:45 AM", "sunset": "05:43 PM" } ], "date": "2015-08-03",  "hourly": [ {"chanceoffog": "0", "chanceoffrost": "0", "chanceofhightemp": "0", "chanceofovercast": "0", "chanceofrain": "0", "chanceofremdry": "0", "chanceofsnow": "0", "chanceofsunshine": "100", "chanceofthunder": "0", "chanceofwindy": "0", "cloudcover": "0", "DewPointC": "-3", "DewPointF": "26", "FeelsLikeC": "9", "FeelsLikeF": "48", "HeatIndexC": "9", "HeatIndexF": "47", "humidity": "43", "precipMM": "0.0", "pressure": "1028", "tempC": "9", "tempF": "47", "time": "200", "visibility": "10", "weatherCode": "113",  "weatherDesc": [ {"value": "Clear" } ]}
```

really unsure what I have done wrong here. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which line of code there is error?Could you paste this line?

Comment: its in the first line of the response data. The unexpected token is in the response and not the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah made a stupid mistake and I did not think on the problem long enough... The error occurred because I forgot to add `'callback=JSON_CALLBACK'` to the end of my jsonp call... will leave this answer here if it will help anyone else...

Answer (score 1):

You can parse JSON for better results:

```
$scope.localWeather = JSON.parse(weather);
```

But i checked your json output with [JSON lint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it sais that the JSON is wrong. 
Could you check in developer console if The same JSON comes from weather service as you outputted? if yes, then it is a problem with api, with which you cannot do anything.

Comment: thanx for the answer. I am still receiving the error so I am going to try contact worldweatheronline.com and will see if I receive a response.